# Undesirable offset in the display

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following css code for drawing familly trees:

```
.tree ul {
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top; /* added this */
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  /*the padding is 20px + border-top = 23px*/
  padding: 23px 5px 0 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}


/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before,
.tree li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 3px solid #ccc;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
}

.tree li::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 3px solid #ccc;
}


/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/

.tree li:only-child::after,
.tree li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}


/*Remove space from the top of single children*/

.tree li:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}


/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/

.tree li:first-child::before,
.tree li:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}


/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/

.tree li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 3px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.tree li:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}


/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/

.tree ul ul::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 3px solid #ccc;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
}

.tree li .family {
  position: relative;
}


/* Person */

.person {
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 150px;
  /* min-height: 100px ;
  to increase the min height of the boxes background-color: #FFFFFF; */
  display: inline-block;
}

.person.female {
  border-color: #F45B69;
  top: 0px
}

.person.male {
  top: 0px;
  border-color: #456990;
}

.person .content {
  position: relative;   
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Globally, this works well, but unfortunately, an offset appears in the display of the blocks.
As a simple example, the following html code

```
<html>

<HEAD>
<title> Family tree </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<META http-equiv="content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</HEAD>

<body bgcolor="white" background="" vlink="peru" alink="peru" link="peru">

<b>

<div class="tree" align=center>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="person child male">
                <div class="content">
                    some very very big familly name
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul >
                <li>
                    <div class="person child male">
                        <div class="content">Uncle</div>
                    </div>              
                </li>                   
            </ul>       
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Produce the following display:

[image: tree]

We see that the second block is offset to the right with respect to the first block, while it should be centered just below it.

Comment: The code posted doesn't produce the result in the image

Comment: I believe this was because of the missing dot .tree. Mistake corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I look at it using the element inspector, I see an additional `padding-inline-start: 40px;` in `ul`. Perhaps this is the default style for `ul`. You can choose to remove it. To make the child centered, maybe you can use `display: flex`

Try changing

```
tree ul {
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

to

```
.tree ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-inline-start: 0;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

Comment: Oh yes, the dot disappeared when I copy my code. But it is already included in my code. Regarding padding-inline-start, your solution works with this example, but if one changes the "familly name" to "some very very big familly name", this does not work anymore.

Comment: hmmm good point. do you want the "child" to be centered, or do you want to have the child be the same width as the parent?  if just centered is enough, you can try using display: flex. I modified the code to include that

Comment: Thank you. Have you tried that? in my tries, this produces rather catastrophic results, like the two blocked are now glued and the whole tree is left justified.

Comment: I tried it with the sample code you provided and it works for me. What does the full code look like?

Comment: I may have messed something (I'm good at that). I am checking that.

Comment: OK. I've edited my question and posted the whole code I am using for testing. I've tested with your suggestion in the css and this produces the catastrophic results said above. I don't understand why.

Comment: I finally obtained everything right with a mix of your answer and that of Prince (see my comment under his answer). No flex box, but your "padding-inline-start: 0;" and "justify-content: center" are wonderful. Thank you so many.

Comment: OK great! You are welcome, glad to have helped. I will study your solution too, to see what I was missing.

Comment: I'm so sorry, in my original answer, I missed a semi-colon. I have added it as an edit. Not sure if that was the issue but still glad you managed to find the solution

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `style="padding: 0;"` to your second `<ul>`

like : `<ul style="padding: 0;">`

```css
tree ul {
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top; /* added this */
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  /*the padding is 20px + border-top = 23px*/
  padding: 23px 5px 0 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}


/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before,
.tree li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 3px solid #ccc;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
}

.tree li::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 3px solid #ccc;
}


/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/

.tree li:only-child::after,
.tree li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}


/*Remove space from the top of single children*/

.tree li:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}


/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/

.tree li:first-child::before,
.tree li:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}


/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/

.tree li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 3px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.tree li:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}


/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/

.tree ul ul::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 3px solid #ccc;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
}

.tree li .family {
  position: relative;
}


/* Person */

.person {
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 150px;
  /* min-height: 100px ;
  to increase the min height of the boxes background-color: #FFFFFF; */
  display: inline-block;
}

.person.female {
  border-color: #F45B69;
  top: 0px
}

.person.male {
  top: 0px;
  border-color: #456990;
}

.person .content {
  position: relative;   
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree" align=center>
<ul>
  <li>
      <div class="person child male">
          <div class="content">
              some familly name  
          </div>
      </div> 
      <ul style="padding: 0;">
          <li>
              <div class="person child male">
                  <div class="content">Uncle</div>
              </div>              
          </li>                   
      </ul>       
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I did this and this does not solved the problem with my browser (Firefox). I am trying to understand what happens here.

Comment: It appears you solution remove the space and the bar between the two blocks. Definitely not the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```css
<style>
    .tree > ul {
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree ul li ul {
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
} 

.tree li {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top; /* added this */
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  /*the padding is 20px + border-top = 23px*/
  padding: 23px 5px 0 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}


/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before,
.tree li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 3px solid #ccc;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
}

.tree li::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 3px solid #ccc;
}


/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/

.tree li:only-child::after,
.tree li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}


/*Remove space from the top of single children*/

.tree li:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}


/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/

.tree li:first-child::before,
.tree li:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}


/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/

.tree li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 3px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.tree li:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}


/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/

.tree ul ul::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 3px solid #ccc;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
}

.tree li .family {
  position: relative;
}


/* Person */

.person {
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 150px;
  /* min-height: 100px ;
  to increase the min height of the boxes background-color: #FFFFFF; */
  display: inline-block;
}

.person.female {
  border-color: #F45B69;
  top: 0px
}

.person.male {
  top: 0px;
  border-color: #456990;
}

.person .content {
  position: relative;   
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}

</style>
```

```html
<div class="tree" align="center">
   <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="person child male">
                <div class="content">
                    some familly name  
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="person child male">
                        <div class="content">Uncle</div>
                    </div>              
                </li>                   
            </ul>       
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code works on the snippet, but does not produce the same result in my browser (Firfox). I am currently trying to understand why.

Comment: OK. This works with this example, but now if the name in the first block is larger, like "some very very big familly name", then the offset appears again at the other side.

Comment: I found that all what is missing from your solution for working fully is a "justify-content: center" inside your added code, that I borrowed from the answer of alph. Also, his "padding-inline-start: 0" solved other problems of undesirable spacing in my tree. The solution is now complete, thanks to both of you.